# Struggling to get around Canvas Command Failed

Tags: node.js, npm, canvas

First time user here.  I've been trying to install a file via Visual Code but keep running into the same error log.  I haven't been able to find locate any real documentation on how to get around it so I figured I'd come to the experts. I see this canvas command failed error a lot which leads into the pre-gyp and gyp info errors you'll see below.

Error Log below:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.5
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@17.0.1 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for canvas@2.8.0 and node@17.0.1 (node-v102 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp) 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.0.1 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info ok 
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@17.0.1 | darwin | x64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.8.9 found at "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/amjcramer/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/amjcramer/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/amjcramer/Library/Caches/node-gyp/17.0.1/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! /bin/sh: pkg-config: command not found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config pixman-1 --libs' returned exit status 127 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:353:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:290:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "configure" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node" "--module_name=canvas" "--module_path=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=0" "--node_napi_label=node-v102"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v8.2.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error 
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute '/usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js configure --fallback-to-build --module=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node --module_name=canvas --module_path=/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas/build/Release --napi_version=8 --node_abi_napi=napi --napi_build_version=0 --node_napi_label=node-v102' (1)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/@mapbox/node-pre-gyp/lib/util/compile.js:89:23)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:390:28)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1062:16)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:301:5)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.1.0
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /Users/amjcramer/Desktop/hashlips_art_engine/node_modules/canvas
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v17.0.1
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v1.0.5
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! not ok
```

Is there anyone who can provide insight into what might be missing? I've tried several different strategies but have not been able to get around the error codes.

I am working off of a Mac with the latest upgrade; macOS Monterey, installed - I don't think that this is causing the issue but I'm just getting into all this.

Comment: npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET `https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases/download/v2.8.0/canvas-v2.8.0-node-v102-darwin-unknown-x64.tar.gz`
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status `404 Not Found`

Comment: There is no `v102` in the releases: https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/releases